# How to call previous event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I am hooking all events of a usercontrol (RegisterClassHandler) because in my context (Excel Add-In) I need to use the "en-US" culture in the code behind and then restore the local culture once the event has been handled.

I know that adding a handler is a chained mecanism (i.e. once my handler code is completed the previous handler's code will be called).

How can I break this chain and call the previous handler before the end without triggering the event again ?

For instance if I use between the 2 `Thread.CurrentThead.CurrentCulture` : `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<object, RoutedEventArgs>(NewHandler), sender, e);` the event is triggered again and again until I get a stack overflow exception.

Here is the code

```
    public class CultureEnUsUserControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _previousCulture;

    public CultureEnUsUserControl()
    {
        Loaded += SafeCultureEnUsUserControlLoaded;
        _previousCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    }

    void SafeCultureEnUsUserControlLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents();
        foreach (var routedEvent in events)
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(CultureEnUsUserControl), routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(NewHandler));
    }

    internal void NewHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        //Here I want to call the previous event handler without triggering again the event

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _previousCulture;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just assuming you manage to call another registered event handler from your own handler, then this handler will be called twice (either it has been already invoked by the event before your handler is being called, or it will be invoked again after your handler returns). That approach looks error-prone to me. Also, there is no such concept as "original handler". An event can have *n* handlers registered, neither of them is less or more original then the others...